# How do I change the y axis on facetgrid python to percentage?

Tags: python, charts, histogram, data-analysis, yaxis

Python matplotlib sns facetgrid y axis question

Hello!

I've been learning about python for data analysis and I'm stuck on something I can't find an answer to.

I want to change the y axis on my sns facegrid chart to a percentage. Below is the code and image...

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data, col = 'Survived')
g.map(plt.hist, 'Age', bins=20)
```

Here is the output:

[image: Here's the output]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `density=True`, see [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib-pyplot-hist).

Then change the y-label to percentages, like this [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_percent_demo.html).

Which results in;

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col='smoker', col_order=['Yes','No'])
g.map(plt.hist, 'total_bill', density=True, bins=20, color='m')

from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
def to_percent(y, position):
    s = str(100*y)
    return s + '%'
formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

[image]